# C# - XNA - Draw part of GameComponent after both GameComponent

Tags: c#, xna

I have problem width draw's layer depth in XNA. I have two GameComponents: ScreenManager and Ball. ScreenManager has screens: BackgroundScreen, GamePlayScreen, and PauseScreen...

I need draw ball before PauseScreen and draw BackgroundScreen before ball, currently...

In Ball GameComponent, I tried call base.Draw() after I draw ball's sprite and in ScreenManager I tried call base.Draw() before I draw screen, but both is non-functional.

How do I do it?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Create more than one game component?

Comment: I don't understand. I have two components: Screen manager and Ball.

Comment: Sorry - I should have said: Create more than *two* game components. Or: Create more than one game component that can display screens. Another alternative is to change the draw order manually.

Comment: Thanks for advice, but I believe in better "ordering" than create more component... I think that it isn't best possible ordering. What do you think: "change the draw order manually"?

Answer (score 2):

You can't achieve this in your current setup, because GameComponents can only change their "Draw-Order" in relation to each other.

Here is a picture visualizing this:

[image]

As you can see Ball and ScreenManager are in the same plane/layer, so rearranging doesn't solve your problem.

To solve your question, you can make the Screens GameComponents as well or you move the logic of your ball in a separate screen.